# Change pivot point for selected edges

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to change the pivot point for selected edges/vertecies in edit mode?

My situation is as follows:
[image]

I want to extrude selected edges and scale them down a little. For this I would need the pivot point to be located in the center (approximately where the 3d cursor is). 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Simply change the pivot point to 3D cursor. THe icon just to the right of the wireframe one on the bottom toolbar

Comment: How can I do that in edit mode?
In object mode the cursor is right where I want it, but when I switch to edit mode, it jumps back according to the selection.

Comment: The 3D cursor or the transform widget?

Comment: select the first and the last vertex, then Shift S cursor to selected, so the 3D cursor will be exacly at the center of the two vertex. Then, as said, change the pivot to 3D cursor and operate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You change the pivot point in edit mode by clicking on the pivot point icon in the information header (OK, in the 3D viewport it's actually a footer) and selecting the option you want. In this case, in object mode you can use set origin (<kbd>SHFT</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to set the origin where you want it, then set the 3D cursor to the origin using the snap tool (<kbd>SHFT</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>) selecting "cursor to active, because in object mode if vertices in the object are selected, the object is active, and the cursor snaps to the origin. The 3D cursor does not move when you go back to edit mode, so you can use the 3D cursor as the pivot point.

In the illustration you included with your question, I assume the blue dot is the origin point, so the 3D cursor is already where it will be, and all you need do is as suggested in the comment: change the pivot point to the 3D cursor in the "pivot point for rotation scaling" in the 3D viewport header..

Comment: Thank you. I somehow completely missed the pivot point mode selection button/widget. Dooh. Seems so simple now..
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with a randomly placed 3D cursor and an object origin at the center:
[image]

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> select *Cursor to Center*.

<kbd>RMB</kbd> the first and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd> the last edge you want to extrude.

[image]

Make sure that 3D cursor is select as pivot point

[image]

<kbd>E</kbd> (extrude) <kbd>S</kbd> (scale) will extrude and scale the previously selected edges.

[image]